# What is the best way to rename a class in an iOS library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated

If I wanted to rename a class that is widely used within my iOS library and whose API is also publicly exposed, what would be the best way to do that?
Ideally, I'd like to have the old name still around, marked with a deprecation warning so people can switch to using the new syntax gracefully. But because I can't keep both classes around I would want the developer to still be able to use the deprecated API but it internally simply calls the renamed version of itself.

I was playing around with `#define`, `__attribute__((deprecated))` and `@compatibility_alias` but didn't find a way to accomplish all of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you use refactor to rename you class to new name.
then, you want to support old name but with a depreciate, you can use typedef statement:

`__attribute__((deprecated)) typedef NewClassName OldClassName;`

Comment: Perfect! This exactly what I was looking for. A shame I didn't think of `typedef` myself :)

Comment: This will work if the *only* change is a new name and there no functional changes in the new class. Also, this will allow users to call new method names on the old class.

Answer (score 2):

Say you're renaming `ABC` to `XYZ`.

You can use the refactoring tool (Edit -> Refactor -> Rename…) to rename `ABC` to `XYZ`. You may need to do some manual file renaming as well.

If you want to still support `ABC` after the rename, you'll need to create a new class called `ABC` that forwards messages to `XYZ`. On the new "fake" `ABC` class, mark all the methods as deprecated.

You could implement these all by hand. Or, if the new class's structure isn't radically different, you could use [message forwarding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html):

> However, before announcing the error, the runtime system gives the receiving object a second chance to handle the message.

Basically, don't implement the methods on the new "fake" `ABC` - just implement `forwardInvocation:` to pass them to the correct class.

Comment: This would probably also work but the `typedef` is way simpler and less fragile. Nice idea though. Would probably enable some more complex use cases then mine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it :) I assumed the new class had some functional differences.